# Mongoose Client-Side Field Level Encryption

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, encryption

I want to know if there is a way to set up Client-Side Field Level Encryption with Mongoose.  Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8167#issuecomment-562869693

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this npm module 'mongoose-field-encryption'. More info [here https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-field-encryption](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-field-encryption)